# How can I determine the end of a SQLite db file from a hex view of the hard disk?

Tags: python, sqlite, hex, data-recovery

I have a HDD that may have deleted SQLite db files on it. I am reading the bytes of the disk and looking for the hex signature of SQLite files: `53514c69746520666f726d6174203300`

My code tells me the offsets of these files on disk but I don't know what size they are.

e.g. offsets

- 760360
- 935448

Is it possible to determine the size of the dbs from the hex view? As far as I can tell, there is no common end characters for these files.

My code

```
from pathlib import Path
import logging

file_sig = '53514c69746520666f726d6174203300'
disk = Path('/dev/sde1')  # sde is old HDD
try:
    with disk.open(mode="rb") as drive:
        for block_no in range(0, 488281250):
            byte = drive.read(512)
            hexx = byte.hex()

            try:
                idx = hexx.index(file_sig)
                byte_nos.append(idx + block_no * 512)
            except ValueError as e:
                logging.debug(e)
                pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

with Path('./results.csv').open(mode='w') as f:
    for item in byte_nos:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: You can extract the page size and total page count from the header and work out how many blocks are used. There's no guarantee the files are stored contiguously by the filesystem, though...

Comment: And where is the header if I'm looking at a hex view of the entire hard drive? If I check a SQLite db file there's [not much going on at the beginning of the file](https://i.imgur.com/PJYATCR.png)

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/tP6qtp1i) is an example of the hex at the start of a SQLite file

Comment: Ok, I found [this](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs3311/18s1/documentation/sqlite3/fileformat2.html) very helpful guide to the first few bytes of a SQLite db. Thanks!

Comment: generally, to parse broken sqlite pages, you can use [sqlite3.ksy](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/master/database/sqlite3.ksy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file size can be determined by looking at the header in hex.

I will use a section of the header from the incorrect answer that *forgetso* provided to demonstrate. We only need to examine the first 32 bytes, so this is the section we'll look at:

> 53 51 4C 69 74 65 20 66
> 6F 72 6D 61 74 20 33 00
> 10 00 01 01 00 40 20 20
> 00 00 CC 9B 00 00 03 2B

The first 16 bytes are the file type identifier, so we really only are concerned with this section to determine file size:

> **10 00** 01 01 00 40 20 20
> 00 00 CC 9B 00 00 03 2B

The two byte section (offset 16 and 17) in bold above will tell us the size of each page contained in the database. In order to get that number we must convert the big endian hex representation into decimal form. This can be done quickly using a hex to decimal conversion tool.

> **10 00**

becomes 4096, which means each page is ***4096 bytes***.

The other part we need is the number of pages contained in the database.

> 10 00 01 01 00 40 20 20
> 00 00 CC 9B **00 00 03 2B**

Looking at the above hex again, the four byte section (offset 28-32) that is now bold is what we need to determine the total number of pages. Again, we simply need to convert into decimal form.

> **00 00 03 2B**

becomes 811, which means there are ***811 pages***.

Simply multiply these values to calculate the database file size.

```
4096(bytes/page) * 811(pages) = 3321856
```

So, the file size is ***3,321,856 bytes***.
*The end of the file would be found by adding this number to the offset where the header begins.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shawn I found [this](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ecs3311/18s1/documentation/sqlite3/fileformat2.html) very helpful guide to SQLite databases.

> Beginning with SQLite version 3.7.1, a page size of 65536 bytes is
> supported. The value 65536 will not fit in a two-byte integer, so to
> specify a 65536-byte page size, the value is at offset 16 is 0x00
> 0x01.

The start of my db files look like:

```
53514C69746520666F726D617420330010000101004020200000CC9B0000032B000002E1
000000170000008000000002000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000CC9B00
```

So I *think* my page size is 0001 = 65536 bytes even though this seems to be at offset 15 (maybe a case of counting from 0 versus 1). The number of pages is stored at offset 28 if...

> the 4-byte change counter at offset 24 exactly matches the 4-byte
> version-valid-for number at offset 92

In my case the change counter offset seems to be "00CC9B00" at these offsets. Therefore, I take my page count to be 0000032B which converts to a big endian 8 bit value of 43.

```
43 (page count) * 65536 (page size) = 2,818,048 bytes = 2.818048 MB
```

This is close to what the file explorer in Ubuntu tells me but it's not correct. I know my test db is 3,321,856 bytes so I'm about 503,808 bytes short. When searching for the files, I'll just extend the part of the disk I grab by this much as I'm only trying to search the raw files for certain text, not load them as databases.